# How to Block Right Click on Flash Player in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, flash

I have embedded the flash player(Shockwave Flash Object) into my application Form. and then I want to block right click from user. The question is that can I block right click from user?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You could embedd your Flash content using the `WebBrowser` control and set the `IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled` to *False* but I admit that this solution would be the proverbial sledgehammer to crack the nut.

If you want to use [System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d67hf8a), just specify the desired Flash content as the `Navigate` target:

```
Public Class Form1 Inherits Form
    Public Sub New()
        webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = False
        webBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri(string_variable_path_to_flash))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There's really not much to it - see an example in my updated answer.